# Rails:Can we perform data validation on the controller side for a UI wizard?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a rails application where I pre-process some data fetched from a service call. I retain this data in the session.

Further, I maintain other pieces of data in the session variables as to which step is being validated and what is the expected data that should be input by the user.

I use this data to validate inputs that is entered via a UI wizard. I'm currently validating this data on the controller side as it did not seem to make sense for the controller to send this data to the model and get it validated there.

Is it ok to do this? Or does this violate the "fat model- skinny controller" approach?

Comment: Did you try [validation.js](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation), its a client side validation using jquery

Comment: Check [this](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/263-client-side-validations) also ..

Comment: Hi @ShreshttBhatt . I do not want to perform client side validation because I'm developing the application for a low memory device with a primitive browser. I do not want to overload its memory. Hence I need to do server side validation.